# Appstore as modal view in iOS6

Tags: xcode, app-store, ios6

I noticed that when the user taps an **app store link in the iOS6 mail app**, mail **opens a modal view representing the app store** instead of switching to the App Store app as it did in previous versions.

Does Apple provide access to this capability, or it is exclusive to their integrated programs?

---

**Note:** If you have iOS 6 and want test it, just open appstore and email app to yourself.

Comment: So no NDA now I guess, anyone will answer :)

Comment: This is not a documented feature of iOS6

Comment: I believe that appstore is just a webview. If you can figure out the URL you could probably just display it in a webview.

Comment: endy may be right:  can you post a screenshot from your iOS device or the simulator that shows the view you are talking about?

Comment: I've just noticed this too. Here are the shots: [inside Mail app](http://imageshack.us/a/img337/9380/photo1r.png), once clicked you get [AppStore modal view](http://imageshack.us/a/img196/4306/photo2ye.png)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I added this method as a category to UIViewController, but you can repurpose it for your own needs. The app store ID is the big number in the app store URL. Make sure you import the StoreKit framework and header file!

```
@import StoreKit;

- (void)presentAppStoreForID:(NSNumber *)appStoreID withDelegate:(id<SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate>)delegate
{
    if(NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController")) { // Checks for iOS 6 feature.

        SKStoreProductViewController *storeController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
        storeController.delegate = delegate; // productViewControllerDidFinish

        // Example App Store ID (e.g. for Words With Friends)
        // @322852954

        [storeController loadProductWithParameters:@{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: appStoreID }
                                   completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
            if (result) {
                [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:nil];
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh!" message:@"There was a problem opening the app store" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
            }
        }];

    } else { // Before iOS 6, we can only open the App Store URL
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@",appStoreID]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Do you know if there a way to use that method with app store affiliate program? Because it seem no way to pass the pratnerID and siteID to the appstore

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar with the affiliate program

Comment: A couple of people have looked at this since I answered. To add a little more detail, I highly recommend a UIActivityIndicatorView starting before you call loadProductWithParameters -- it can be quite slow. Additionally, if you only have the appStore URL you can put your code to extract the appStoreID number in this method (I only kept them separate because our model happened to already store them separately). Finally, make sure to replace the Alert view text with something relevant to your application.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but when I test this on the dev iPhone I am not able to install apps, is that because it is not in appstore yet and works on test device?

Comment: iTarek, you have to set up a special account in iTunes Connect for that. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com > Manage Users > Test Users > Add a new user. I know you don't have to use a real email address for test users, but I'm not sure if you have to use a real credit card.

Comment: Just a small fix. iTunes ID shouldn't be the number `[NSNumber numberWithInt:322852954]` but a string object: `_The value associated with this key should be a string representing the iTunes identifier..._` [^](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: This actually doesn't do anything for me. I have tried on the device as well as the simulator. I put a breakpoint in the if (result) and else statement, but it never breaks there. Whats going on?

Comment: @SoftDesigner, while the key itself is posted as `NSString`, the description say this `The value associated with this key is an instance of NSNumber, representing the iTunes identifier for the item you want the store to display when the view controller is presented.` It works for both thought, so i am not sure which one to pick....

Comment: @AndreiG. The latest documentation says to use an `NSNumber`—possibly @SoftDesigner linked to documentation that was later corrected? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html

Comment: This worked however cannot write a review in it :(. I will up vote this for sure though.

Comment: @iTarek in iOS 8 you will be able to add an affiliate identifier with `SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken` and (optionally) `SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is introduced in IOS 6 as StoreKit, specifically [SKITunesProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852) which allows you to present iTunes contents (apps, music, books etc.) inside your app for user to purchase directly.

Answer (score -1):

There is a plugin for handling affiliate links here:
https://github.com/adeven/AEProductController

Or you could roll your own by first opening the affiliate link in-app (just as you would before opening the iTunes Store app directly), following the Apple Technical Q&A QA1629:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

and then opening the SKStoreProductViewController as MaxGabriel noted above.

[Edit] I completed this in my app (a music app) but whether I have an active AVAudioSession or I completely disable all playback (for testing), song samples in the modal iTunes Store play but have no sound.  If you don't have this issue or you find a resolution, let me know.  It may be a bug that should be reported to https://bugreport.apple.com/ .

Comment: Have you tried this method? Do you actually earn the affiliate commissions this way? Georiot claims SKStoreProductViewController  doesn't honor affiliate cookies anyway https://twitter.com/georiotdotcom/status/295764495647784960

Comment: `SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken` and `SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken` are included officially in iOS 8, so they should work now.