# Why does url behave differently on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, app-store, ios6

I am trying to launch my page on the app store from my app using the same code that works on iOS 5. Did Apple change the way this works in iOS 6? The app store is launching and saying "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/myname"]];
```

Comment: For iOS 6, you might consider using the new StoreKit API to open the app store without ever leaving your app, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682657/1176156

Comment: Try this link it will help to open developer page . it worked for me
https://itunes.apple.com/artist/company_name/Developerid?mt=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, for solve this, just WAIT. It seems problem in Apple servers.

For additional info click [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1368)

For your problem colleagues click [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot%20connect%20to%20iTunes%20Store,%20ios%206&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

**EDITED**:

If is not server problem, then try just:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8"]];
```

and safari will open a iTunes

Comment: Hello, in the Facebook app, they manage to launch the store app within the facebook app itself! How to?

Comment: @VanDuTran Hi, i think, this is a small web window. Facebook and Twitter can work with AppStore and iTunes at very well. At example, they can get app description text from AppStore link.

Comment: @CReaTuS do you know how they do that?

Comment: @VanDuTran best way to know, create a new question about this.