# StoreKit and LinkShare

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, storekit

Has anyone been successful it leveraging their LinkShare iTunes Affiliates program with iOS 6 StoreKit [SKStoreProductViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011852)? I had hoped that even if you couldn't use LinkShare Link Maker Tool, you could at least pass the [LinkShare Affiliate Token](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store.html#LinkShareToken) in a URL.

I have seen [a couple related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475568/appstore-as-modal-view-in-ios6) that suggest that it is not supported, but they are several months old and don't seem definitive. I was hopeful that the status on this had changed.

Logistically, I'm not sure how you could get it to work with the current definitions. While I could test whether various URL open the ProductView, I'm not sure how you'd know if you received credit from LinkShare or not.

Any updates would be appreciated. Thanks.

Note: While a lot of people are using [StoreKit to implement In-App Purchase](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) of their own items, I'm actually [using it to display / preview / purchase other people's content](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class) (e.g. a Rob Zombie album).

Comment: LinkShare usually takes a few days (up to a week) to show commissions.  Have you tested any purchases using the `SKStoreProductViewController`?

Comment: I found this open-source project called [AEProductController](https://github.com/adeven/AEProductController) that wraps `SKStoreProductViewController` to allow the use of an affiliate token, but I haven't tested it.  It seems like there's [some controversy](https://twitter.com/georiot/status/295764495647784960) about whether the `SKStoreProductViewController` honors affiliate cookies properly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [recent thread](https://github.com/adeven/AEProductController/issues/1#issuecomment-23863073) for the [AEProductController](https://github.com/adeven/AEProductController) project, which basically says that the project does not work.

So it looks like that there is currently no way to leverage affiliate programs with SKStoreProductViewController. Everyone who wants that functionality should probably [file a Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) to make Apple aware of the request.