# How to open appstore link without closing app

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store

I want to open an app store link within an app but without closing the app.

You can look for the best example which is [Cut The Rope](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/cut-the-rope-free/id394613472)

It opens the link with a modal view controller and looks similar to the view when we press the app icon the app store

As I think it might be a UIWebView presented in moal controller. If guess anything interesting or if you have any answer please let know about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SKStoreProductViewController: [SKStoreProductViewController StoreKit Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html)

Example: [Stackoverflow Answer with same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475568/appstore-as-modal-view-in-ios6)